# add if statement to the featured image

Tags: php, functions, post-thumbnails, images

I have a featured image. I want to add an if statement to the size. For example, if the featured image height exceeds 500px I want to add something.

Is that possible ?

Comment: What have you tried? Please **edit your question** to include your current code.

Comment: @ChipBennett I still didn't try. I want to know if this is possible. I am willing to have posts that are like boxes. If one of the posts have a higher featured image height i want to make it a full width post

Comment: Without seeing your actual code, it's nearly impossible to know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, and where you're having issues.

Comment: To give a little context: the reason that the question can't be answered in its current form is because that, when calling `the_post_thumbnail()`, the return is an image of *a known, specific size*. You might want to have a look at [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) as a starting point.

Comment: @ChipBennett

for the functions.php

`
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
add_image_size( 'featuredimage-homepage', 450, 9999, false );`


my index.php

`<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'featuredimage-homepage' ); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>?>`

Comment: Please file an [edit] and add your code (and any possible progress) to the question.

Answer (score 0):

instead of a lot of code you have 2 ways to achieve your goal

1-use `timthumb`

2- specifying `height` & `width` to your `the_post_thumbnail()`